# How to set div margins for slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an animation that must only be shown within a specific margin. For example, I have a square div from left to right(100px to 500px) and top to bottom(100px and 500x). A picture is inside this square, the picture will animate from left to right. What I want is to progressively hide the picture when it reaches the square left corner until the picture is completely hidden. This is something similar to a sliding banner. I have tried by setting div margins, but did not work. I am using jquery, but I am open to other libraries. Any suggestion, page or anything will be helpful.

This is an example of what I am doing. The id=picture is sliding to 900px, but what I want is to progressively hide the picture once it has reached the 500px of the id=square.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<style>
body{ background-color:#94B8B8;}
</style>
</head>
<body><!--border-color:white-->

<div id="square" style = "width:500px;height:500px;background-color:blue;position:relative;">
<div id="picture" style = "width:100px;height:100px;background-color:white;position:relative;top:50px;left:50px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').mousedown(function(e){
        $("#picture").animate({left:"900px"},1000);
  });
});

</script>
```

Thanks,
Joe|_

Comment: I'd like to see some code, an online demo, a sketch if really necessary, from what currently stands in your Q it's really hard to catch what you mean and what you want.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question and included some code. If something else is needed , please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZaxW/1/

You need to add overflow hidden to the square.

CSS:

```
body{ background-color:#94B8B8;}
#square{overflow:hidden;}
```

Also, you are loading your libraries in the wrong order.  jQuery must be loaded before jQueryUI, although that isn't the issue at hand.

Comment: This assumes by "progressively hide" that you mean it just disappears rather than fades out.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle with one that resets the picture on mousedown before animating it so you can see it happen every time you click instead of only the first time.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/unoqew/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').mousedown(function(e){
        $("#picture").animate({left:350, opacity:0},1000);
    });
});
```